# After minimize black place in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, minimize

Like the title say I've a issue with minimize my program.

If I minimize my window, the old place will be set black and will be hidden after refresh. Screenshot:

[image]

```
private void OnlyStatus_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_zählerStatus % 2 == 0)
        {
            ServerAdministratorWindow.MaxHeight = 690;
            ServerAdministratorWindow.MinHeight = 690;
            ServerAdministratorWindow.MaxWidth = 840;
            ServerAdministratorWindow.MinWidth = 840;
            ServerAdministratorWindow.Width = 840;
            ServerAdministratorWindow.Height = 690;
            _zählerStatus++;
        }
        else if (_zählerStatus % 2 != 0)
        {
            ServerAdministratorWindow.MaxHeight = 80;
            ServerAdministratorWindow.MinHeight = 80;
            ServerAdministratorWindow.MinWidth = 840;
            ServerAdministratorWindow.Height = 80;
            _zählerStatus++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot ?

Comment: Question describes nothing . Post some more information.

Comment: Fixed! Have to change the size for width and height, also if I don't wanna change it.